# MalformedJsonException when reading response using Retrofit2

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2

I'm trying to call an API, which some String fields are empty.
For example:

```
{
"name":"Foo",
"surname":""
}
```

As I want to reuse my code, I'm passing an Object type to the call.

This is how I'm implementing my retrofit instance:

```
return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(properties.getBaseUrl())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

And this is how I'm making the call and parsing JSON:

```
Call<Object> calltargetResponse = apiCalls.getResult(properties.getToken(), param);

        calltargetResponse.enqueue(new Callback<>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, retrofit2.Response<Object> response) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Response res= gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), Response.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unexpected value at line 1 column 2 path $.surname
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1006)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:956)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:905)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:876)
    at com.checkin.checkin.domain.functions.ApiCall$1.onResponse(ApiCall.java:32)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unexpected value at line 1 column 18 path $.msg
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1597)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:564)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.skipValue(JsonReader.java:1232)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:991)
    ... 9 more
```

Note that if I print response.body().toString(), I have the next output:

```
{name=FOO,surname=}
```

Comment: What does the class `Response` contain?

Comment: just name and surname

Comment: Does Response class has both 'name' and 'surname' member variables?

Comment: Yes, as I said, the problem is the Json that is coming from the response: {name=FOO,surname=}, it cannot be parsed

Comment: `{name=FOO,surname=}` is not valid JSON. Or is that when you serialize it differently? (into a map?)

Comment: I know its not a valid json, but it's the json that I'm gettint from the response. This is probably the error, but I don't know how to fix

Comment: If that's indeed the response string you're getting, then you have to fix it server-side. If you don't have access to the server, then you have to serialize it yourself into `Response`.

Comment: server-side it's not a problem. When I call the API using Postman, the result is OK, but I don't know why it's happening this when called via retrofit

Comment: Serverside it is a problem.  If the server is delivering `{name=FOO,surname=}` as a purported JSON response, then that is a bug on the server side.  That is invalid JSON.  (There should be quotes around the attribute names and string values).  The other possibility is that what you are showing us is NOT the JSON that the server is sending.  In that case ... well ... it could be anything and we would be guessing ...

Comment: As I said, server side it's not a problem. When it's called from postman the response is ok, and when it's called from other devices, the response it's also ok

Comment: "I'm passing an Object type to the call"; could you please explain why you are doing this? It looks like Retrofit is already deserializing the JSON to `Object`, then you convert that Object to a (non-JSON) String representation with `toString()` and try to parse it as JSON again. Is it not possible in your use case to specify the exact response type instead of `Call<Object>` and let Retrofit handle the deserialization?